# Visual Studio Code - Browser Preview Not showing same content in downloaded index.html

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When I am using Visual Studio code, I am coding in HTML and CSS.

When I open the Browser Preview button, it shows the changes I am making and some things appear as I want it to be.

However, when I download the saved file as an index.html file, the look does not appear the same as the Browser Preview.

What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- File extension must be `.html`
- Then, first of all make sure that all the time you are saving your file using `ctrl+s`. You can do this automatically by changing in setting.
- You can reinstall any browser preview extension like this one.

[image]

- Restart the VScode and check again whether it's working or not.
- Also, You can setup your vs code again.